# Unique variable naming patterns in deep learning code

Tags: python, pytorch, naming-conventions

Need help on understanding some naming patterns I see so far.

Reading [The Annotated Diffusion Model](https://huggingface.co/blog/annotated-diffusion) source code, notice the camel case of some of the functions:

```
    def Upsample(dim, dim_out=None):
        return nn.Sequential(
            nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode="nearest"),
            nn.Conv2d(dim, default(dim_out, dim), 3, padding=1),
        )
```

I wonder if it is because it returns an object. The function is used like a constructor?

It somehow reminds me `import torch.nn.functional as F` which must have seen millions of times. But couldn't recollect why the capital F here. Google search did not turn out any good answers.

Comment: I think that the camel case naming there is used for functions that return objects that are callable, i.e - can be used as functions. In this case it's an nn.Sequential object to which you can pass a tensor. The capital F is a convention because it's short and hence convenient as typically you use this module many times in DL projects.

Comment: @GilPinsky, my guess too. Just not sure if it is a reasonable pattern to follow; or just a harmless style; or something everyone is doing anyways.

Comment: Typically what I see in well-written projects, they stick to snake case format. It's more popular because it's proven to be easier to read than camel case. In addition, type hints are often provided in top notch projects. If type hints are provided, I don't see any benefit for this naming pattern.

Comment: @GilPinsky We cannot only consider readability of identifiers in isolation. Snake case makes expressions harder to read since the underscore character stand out like an operator. Compare `FooBar-BazQux` to `foo_bar-baz_qux`.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom I concur that in some instances snake case could be confusing, as in the case you describe (even though it is not a well-formatted example as there are no spaces between the variable names and the operator). However, in my opinion it boils down to the prevalence of such cases. I believe that in expectation snake case formatted functions will save reading time. At least for Python this is the standard as defined in PEP8 (see https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names). It is explicitly mentioned that it is in order " to improve readability".